# Any lightweight Flutter Network Image plugin for long lists? (up to 500+ image urls to load)

Tags: flutter

So what I'm looking to achieve is:

1. Display a long list of hotels, each has one single image url. All these retrieved from an API.
2. I need it to be smooth/lightweight, so no noticeable fps drops when loading AND scrolling - caching isn't necessary, but if can be implemented without memory problems that'd be cool. (Always have this problem with IOS devices, tested with iphone 6+ I believe)
3. Options to display placeholder image for when it's loading and when it fails to load regardless of the issue.

What I've tried:

1. Cached Network Image (the most common solution I find. But memory problems for more than 100+ images. IOS users reports app crashing/closing itself either on scroll or after a bit of loading time. Asked in their github's issues and it seems that this is common problem - still no fix. Tried the suggestions there. Still to no avail.
2. Advanced Network Image (screen freezes when loading list, probably because it tries to load all image urls at once), also no option for a placeholder image for when an error occurs, not just while the image is loading.

Anyone has encountered similar circumstances and found a satisfactory solution for an acceptable UX? I thought this would be a common enough use case to display a long list of images from network smoothly, but I can't seem to get through this for so long. Pardon me, but I'm a relatively new mobile dev starting to learn the ropes on my own. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: thats a lot of data to load at once, can cause app to be slow or not to respond.You might want to try lazy loading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading

Comment: @Ggriffo yeah I thought about that but I'm looking to see if there's already a good solution out there I can implement right away

Answer (score 3):

You are caching a lot of stuff at once and that may result in unexpected behavior due to network requests + processing (specially on low end devices).

You can first try increasing the `cacheExtent` from your `ListView` to let it start loading before actually reaching the elements and give you a more smooth experience.

```
    ListView.builder(
          cacheExtent: 1500, // Play with this offset value, by default is 250 pixels
          itemCount: items.length,
          itemBuilder: (_, __) => CachedNetworkImage(child: YourWidget()),
        );
```

However, don't increase that value too much because it will force the users to cache content beforehand which may be unnecessary, that's why `ListView` uses lazy building to load content on demand.

Comment: Sorry, just got time to check back. I'll try the cacheExtent with CachedNetworkImage again. But just fyi, I'm already using ListView builder with ListTile as child and the Image is sitting inside that ListTile for every tile. I'll let you know how it goes. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Ok I tried using no plugins. I use FadeInImage with NetworkImage inside. It seems to START loading the list smoothly (no fps drops), but the app crashes on scroll -- this only happens in iOS apparently (so far at least). Any idea? Log doesn't show any error message, literally just app exiting. I'm quite lost. No caching so what could the problem be now?

Comment: Try running on Xcode and you should have a log when app crashes. Post it here.

Comment: Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue

Comment: Tried lowering ImageCache maximumSize from 1000 to 50, still got that message. What's going on?

Comment: Would you mind to try in a different iOS device (eg. iPhone X or above)? Does that still happen?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't currently have access to the newer versions of iOS devices. But I've come to find out that this maybe a memory issue. What I do have access to is my Android device, a Mi 9T with a 6GB RAM and it is running the app smoothly with no memory related crashes...as opposed to an iphone 6+ with 1GB RAM. 

Are you aware of any flutter solutions that achieves what Picasso/Glide does for android? I notice ALL the images are getting pre-loaded as opposed to only loading the ones relevant to scroll position.

Comment: To get around this, I use Extended Image pakcage It's constructors take a bool ```clearMemoryCacheWhenDispose``` which disposes of images in RAM in scroll lists. You may do that or visit the package code to see how he's doing it, and replicate it.

Answer (score 1):

Use memCacheHeight:   attribute of CachedNetworkImage along with Cache Extend of ListView, it might solve the problem