# How to load gif on network image faster on flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I created a gif search engine by following this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=akMH3UOvYu8&t=3895s). But each gif takes about 3-10seconds to load which affects the user experience.

Here's my code snippet:

```
GridView.builder (
  cacheExtent: 900,
  controller: _gifController,
  shrinkWrap: true,
  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
      crossAxisCount: 3),
  physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
  itemCount: GifList.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return Padding(
      padding:  EdgeInsets.all(0.9),
      child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(27)),
            ),
            child: Image.network(
                GifList[index],
                height: 46,
                width:46,
                cacheHeight: 46,
                cacheWidth: 46,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                loadingBuilder: (BuildContext context, Widget child,
                    ImageChunkEvent loadingProgress) {
                  if (loadingProgress == null) {
                    return child;
                  }
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                      value: loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes != null
                          ? loadingProgress.cumulativeBytesLoaded /
                          loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes
                          : null,
                  );
                })),
      ),
    );
  },
)
```

Even when I load one gif using

```
Image.network(https://c.tenor.com/spSgkqK707kAAAAM/ok-all.gif, fit: BoxFit.cover),
```

It can still take up to 8 seconds.

I have tried cacheWidth and cacheHeight, following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61096423/15630845), and tried increasing cache extent following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59732847/15630845). But the loading still takes as long.

I've also seen suggestions on using Cached Network Image. However, since it is a gif search engine, searching for many gif could present a memory problem.

Is there a way to get the gif to show faster? Any suggestion is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just load big size gifs... use tinygif for preview